# Rails count page views of all the posts that belong to a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ruby on rails site which has a user model and a post model

```
# models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

# models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  is_impressionable
end
```

As you can see, I've used the [impressionist gem](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) to count each post's page views.
To get a particular post's page view count, I use post.impressionist_count.

How do I efficiently get the sum of page views of all the posts by a particular user? It's preferable to store this value in a database, as I may need it for more operations. Also, if I store this value in a database, how do I update it each time a post's view count changes? Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Thank you all for your answers. I've tried to incorporate your solutions, but I'm still not able to find one.

I used counter_cache

```
add_column :posts, :view_count, :integer, default: 0

# models/post.rb
is_impressionable :counter_cache => true, :column_name => :view_count
```

Added a column to the user table

```
add_column :users, :total_view_count, :integer, default: 0
```

Then did this

```
# posts_controller
before_action :update_user_total_view_count, only: :show

private
    def update_user_total_view_count
        @post = Post.find(params[:id]);
        @post.user.update_user_total_view_count
    end

# user model
def update_user_total_view_count
    update(total_view_count: posts.sum(:view_count))
end
```

I can't use posts.sum(:impressionist_count) as it is not a  column in the database. I thought I had got this working, but the view_count on the post model doesn't update properly and is stuck at 1 even though the impressionist_count increases. Any solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Is the post viewed on it's own page? So it has it's own controller action for displaying the post?

Comment: @RichardAE, Yes, each post has its own page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'd create an attribute on the user model:

```
rails g migration add_total_post_views_to_users total_post_views:integer
```

Then have a before action on the show action (Controller):

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :update_total_post_views, only: :show

  def show 
    # code for displaying the post
  end

  private

  def update_total_post_views
    Post.find(params[:id]).user.update_total_post_views
  end
```

User Model:

```
class User
  has_many :posts

  # more code...

  def update_total_post_views
     update(total_post_views: posts.sum(:impressionist_count)
  end
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in  accepting your answer. I also used counter_cache as suggested by Paweł Dawczak. Thanks. The solution is in the update but it only works with unique impressions. To make it work for all impressions, I used "is_impressionable :counter_cache => true, :column_name => :view_count, :unique => :all" in the post model.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make something like this:

```
total_impressions = Rails.cache.fetch("user:#{particular_user.id}:total_impressions") do
  Post.where(user: particular_user).reduce(0) do |sum, post|
    sum + post.impressionist_count(:filter=>:all)
  end
end
```

As you can see this code calculate total impressions count and cache it.

I don't known `impressionist` gem very well but probably it is possible to improve this code and make calculation of total impressions on DB side.

Comment: You can 1) invalidate cache manually 2) Set [expiration](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store/fetch) time. I recommend the second way because it is appropriate in current case.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use ActiveRecord built-in mechanism of `counter_cache`, you are defining new column which will store the cached value. There is very quick description how to proceed:

https://coderwall.com/p/tlvgag/easily-keep-track-of-rails-relationship-count-with-counter_cache

What described above is to implement the solution on your own, but the gem has it's own way to store cached counter. Have you tried what is described here?

https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist#adding-a-counter-cache

Comment: Hmm... Yes, I think you have fair point - I misunderstood the problem in first place...